# Weird Screen Size of the Scene Builder of JavaFX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

My Scene Builder got some problem in displaying items. All the items seem like being enlarged. I have already tried to reinstall the IntelliJ and Java JDK. However, everything is fine when I use Gluon Screen Builder.

This is what I see when I am using the Scene Builder in IntelliJ. Everything seems like be enlarged / in a wrong resolution.
[image]

When I am using the Gluon Screen Builder, everything is fine
[image]

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Scene builder inside of intelliJ is weird. You can map your intelliJ so that when you right click and click open in Scenebuilder on your JXML files they'll open inside of Gluon Screen Builder. I'd suggest doing that.

Here's how to map your scenebuilder: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/preparing-for-javafx-application-development.html